# Python 2.7, regex into an array or variable

Tags: regex, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

```
    import re

    regex = r"\d"
    regex1 = r"no"

    str = " 1 blah no blah blah, 5 blah no blah blah "

    matches = re.findall(regex, str)
    matches1 = re.findall(regex1, str)

    for match in matches:
        for match1 in matches1:
            print ("SL %s is %s" % (match, match1))
```

This is the closest that I have come to a solution.

Output:

SL 1 is no

SL 1 is no

SL 5 is no

SL 5 is no

I have tried:

regex = r"\d | no"

regex = r"\d and no"

regex = r"\bh\d\b | \bno\b"

regex = (r"[\d] + no")

and various other combinations.

Tried reading the python regex docs, which is daunting and confusing.

What I am trying to do is search strings for a number (which is an equipment slot number) and a keyword (such as no), preferably all into separate variables, array, or a tuple. Then I can use the variables in another string (telnet command). The purpose is to get an equipment list, which could consist of the same type of card in different slots. The slots and type of cards need to be differentiated for telnet commands.

Any suitable links, suggestions or advice would be appreciated.
Learning Python by the way.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It makes some sense to me. Try [this code](https://ideone.com/QEjSM1). The regex should capture an integer number and any following words as few as possible up to the first *specific* whole word. `re.findall` returns a list of tuples here as there are 2 matches. BTW, I find Python `re` quite clear as far as the use of `re.findall` and `re.finditer` is concerned.

Comment: That code is much better than what I had. will try to tweak it to what I need. THX.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually match and *capture* the parts of the number + any number of spaces/word chars up to and including the specific keyword of your choice using

```
(\d+)\s*([\w\s]*\bno)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnudCG/1).

The regex should capture an integer number and any following words as few as possible up to the first specific whole word. The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method returns a list of tuples here as there are 2 matches.

**Pattern details**

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `([\w\s]*\bno)` - Group 2: zero or more word or whitespace chars followed with a whole word `no`
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QEjSM1):

```
import re

rx = r"(\d+)\s*([\w\s]*\bno)\b"
s = " 1 blah no blah blah, 5 blah no blah blah "
tpl = re.findall(rx, s)
print(tpl)
# => [('1', 'blah no'), ('5', 'blah no')]
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the "blah" part. The  integer will always be first representing the slot  (SL) number, but the "no" part will represent the type of card such as WSS, OSC, MLA, or MLA2. When listing the SL then the type of card, the "extra" words" need to be omitted.    So, I have opted  to use user input for the SL#'s for the cards instead of getting the equipment list and parsing through them. 1 degree consists of an OSC, WSS, and a MLA(2) card and there can be multiple degrees in 1 shelf. So, getting the right slots that correspond to the degrees is paramount.

Comment: @James Could you please translate this comment into something useful for pattern building (if you want further help)? "Extract blah when (not) followed by blah-2... or blah-3 when (not) preceded with blah4". And a couple of real life examples with exact expected outputs.

Comment: @ Wiktor Log into shelf, get equipment list. Then the program lists the degrees and asks which degree to test. (Optical Service Channel (OSC) w/WSC 2 Port SFP 2 Port 10/100BT circuit pack),   (Midstage Line Amplifier (MLA C-Band) circuit pack),   (WSS 100 GHz w/OPM C-Band 2x1 circuit pack).  OSC, WSS, and MLA would need to be extracted along with an integer  (SL# ) that precedes the card description. If multiple cards (WSS and MLA, OSC cards has 2 ports for 2 degrees, then the program would ask which degree would be tested. After user input the system is tested through TL1 commands (telnet).